# Time pulse tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a code that change the Image.
Ive used .after but i want the time (3000ms) adjusteble by a data entry.
How can i do that?

```
muted3 = False
def mute_music3():
    global muted3
    if muted3:
        volumeKnop3.configure(image=volumePhoto3)
        muted3 = False
        root.after(3000, mute_music3)
    else:
        volumeKnop3.configure(image=mutePhoto3)
        muted3 = True

root.after(0, mute_music3)


mutePhoto3 = PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\evanh\\Desktop\\buttonimage\\Time_Done.png")
volumePhoto3 = PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\evanh\\Desktop\\buttonimage\\Time_Not_Done.png")

volumeKnop3 = Button(image=volumePhoto3, command=mute_music3, background="white", activebackground="White", border=0)
volumeKnop3_window = canvas.create_window(30, 200, anchor="nw", window=volumeKnop3)
```

Comment: You can replace `3000` by `int(entry.get())` in `after(...)` where `entry` is an `Entry` widget.

Comment: Just be careful to validate the entry field otherwise you may end up with exceptions being thrown if the entry field doesn't contain a valid number. Personally, I'd have an additional button to allow the time delay to be set